# Lost data after trying to merge two partitions

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, partition-magic

I was using Paragon Partition Manager 10 to merge two partitions, the first of 30GB and the second of 50GB, but my cat unplugged the power cord from the computer and the merge process didnt finish.

Now I cant see my two partitions nor the new partition, and I tried to recover my files with many programs, like "stellar phoenix data recovery", "easeus data recovery", "recuva", etc.
But after many hours!, all the programs detects my lost files , and when I try to recover any file, it has another data (from other of my files).

At this point I don't care to recover all my files, I just want 2 text documents with many many passwords of all my accounts. What can I do?

Comment: sounds like . . the "table of contents" is messed up, the recovery programs trying to use it but it points to the wrong location. to try and find your file, you would have to recover as much as you can, then do a "text containing" type of search of the piles of recovered items, to find out where it is. Other than that ask paragon themselves. they will use a specific method for this merging, which may have included a minor safety net for the operation. a Set of data that a normal recovery would not look into?

Comment: thank you guys, I recover my text files opening my partition with an Hex editor

Answer (score 0):

Being in a similar situation in the past R-Studio was helpful although it can be quite costly - http://www.data-recovery-software.net/. You could try the demo although am unsure what the restrictions are. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a live (bootable) linux system, i.e. such as: http://live.debian.net/

The comforting part is that you can boot from an USB pendrive in no time and have all of the needed functionality out of the box.

A tool I would recommend using for this particular case is "grep". Simply grep the whole drive searching for a familiar pattern - which, in your case, should be a remembered part of a password.. basically a keyword that would lead you to the internals of the aforementioned files, sort of a "search the contents inside a file".

You can also try the photorec/testdisk suite as an alternative resort. However, the method outlined above should be able to locate the clear-text file somewhere on the drive. You can deliberately specify whether to display the text around the matched pattern (to specific boundaries).